# Can't align paragraph next to heading with multi-line wrap

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap, text-alignment

What I want is to have a heading (h2) aligned left with some text (p) to the right of the heading. Paragraph text should also wrap when window is re-sized so that it uses any available space next to the heading. What happens now is the smaller paragraph text wraps under heading leaving a large gap.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9A32/). You will see that text with grey background wraps right under heading leaving a large gap. I want the paragraph to wrap under itself as long as there is enough space.

In case jsfiddle isn't available heres the code:

HTML:

```
<section>
<div>
    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <p>You can Contact Me at sample@smaple.com or use the contact form below:</p>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section{
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
}
section div{
    background-color:#39F;
    border-bottom:3px solid #333;
}
section div h2{
    font-family:helveticaInserat;
    font-size:2.6em;
    display:inline;
    background-color:red;
}
section div p{
    font-family:helveticaInserat;
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

How can this be achieved keeping in mind that all text will be dynamic and it need to wrap when there is little space available?

Answer (score 1):

```
section div h2 {
    font-family:helveticaInserat;
    font-size:2.6em;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}
section div p {
    font-family:helveticaInserat;
    background-color:#CCC;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9A32/2/

Comment: Close, but is there any way to have the paragraph also vertically centered? And why is the border aligning to the paragraph instead of the tallest element(h2)?

Comment: I would like the paragraph (p) v centered so that if for example if I have only 1 line of text it would be in the center of the parent div.

Comment: Vertical centering is somewhat difficult without JS. Would padding on the top paragraph work? http://jsfiddle.net/Z9A32/5/

Comment: That almost works, but I would like it to align top if there's no space for the text to fit without wrapping. I'm ok with js as long as it would revert to align-top if no js is enabled.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the border issue, see http://jsfiddle.net/Z9A32/9/. Any ideas on js solution for vertical centering?

Answer (score 0):

Added float left in `h2`

```
section div h2{
        font-family:helveticaInserat;
        font-size:2.6em;
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9A32/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be using the `display: inline;` attributes. Essentially, you're trying to "float" two block-level elements next to each other. To do so, try something like this:

```
 section div h2{
     width: 45%;
     float: left;
 }

 section div p{
     width: 45%;
     float: left;
 }
```

I'm sure someone with more CSS-fu will be able to give a canonical solution for this, but this is what I've always done. It should resize nicely as you scale the windows.

Comment: Yes, it will resize but will not wrap(both will stay on 1 line)